# Simple python code for writing data to separate files based on condition?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a data set that looks something like

```
[23, 45, 23, 55, 66, 77]
```

I am writing the data to a file using this method (I know there's better ways to write this type of data to a file, but I am using the .format method for specific reasons later on):

```
mydata.write(' '.join(["{}".format(a) for a in data]) + '\n')
```

Now, I have a different data set with the same number of elements as 'data':

```
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

I am wanting to, in the most simple code possible, write all data that corresponds to the '1's in one file, and all the data that corresponds to the '2's in another file.

Comment: @KronoS: numpy *can* be a factor and can actually be a huge help here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah you mean that the solution would include the use of `numpy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can get the datasets you want like this:

```
import numpy
data = numpy.array([23, 45, 23, 55, 66, 77])
pattern = numpy.array([1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2])

set1 = data[pattern == 1]
set2 = data[pattern == 2]
```

Then you just need to save them like you did before.

Comment: much cleaner use of numpy than what i had... this is a very clean way to do it with numpy.

Answer (score 2):

You simply create 2 files as `1.txt` and `2.txt` then we use `zip()` method which zips the two lists and returns a new nested list, and the each element of nested list contains an element form list a and the other from list b.

Then we simply iterate over this new list and check the required conditions and write the data to the relevant file.

```
a  = [23, 45, 23, 55, 66, 77]

b = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]

with open("1.txt", "w") as one , open("2.txt", "w") as two:
    for data in zip(b, a):
        if data[0] == 1:
            one.write(str(data[1])+"\t")
        else:
            two.write(str(data[1])+"\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but it is worth while knowning that a list comprehsion takes a conditional clause:

```
["{}".format(a) for a,m in zip(data,mask) if m==1]
```

and of course a similar expression with `m==2`.

---

Out of curiousity I timed some alternatives:

```
In [188]: data=np.arange(1000)
In [189]: mask=(data%2)==1
```

Time to format the whole array this way.  This respects the OP's choice of `.format`:

```
In [190]: timeit ' '.join(["{}".format(a) for a in data])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop
```

Apply the boolean mask, and then format.  Applying the mask is fast, so this 2x speed is a consequence of having half the values to format:

```
In [191]: timeit ' '.join(["{}".format(a) for a in data[mask]])
1000 loops, best of 3: 527 µs per loop
```

Apply the mask via the comprehension.  Not as good as `data[mask]`, but still not bad:

```
In [192]: timeit ' '.join(["{}".format(a) for a,m in zip(data,mask) if m])
1000 loops, best of 3: 742 µs per loop
```

Curiously using the 'native' format is slower.  Maybe that has to do with breaking the string into lines:

```
In [193]: timeit str(data[mask])
100 loops, best of 3: 5.91 ms per loop
```

Comment: For numpy, there are better options though.

Comment: For small lists, the overhead of creating `numpy` arrays isn't time efficient.  And in this case it isn't clear whether the OP has `numpy` available.

Comment: The question was initially tagged with `numpy`; I rolled back the edit that removed it.